# How to trigger possible data rate of devices? (e.g. for mobile optimization)

Tags: mobile, optimization

In order to optimize any websites with "large" content such as videos, music I want to trigger the possible data rate. Not only trigger that kind of devices like "is_mobile" or "< 800px" etc. because data rate could be different with different connection styles, regional facts etc.

Is there any possibility?